# Calcular soma de dígitos de um número

Tags: python

Escreva um programa que receba um número inteiro na entrada, calcule e imprima a soma dos dígitos deste número na saída. Exemplo:

```
>>> Digite um número inteiro: 123
6
```

Dica: Para separar os dígitos, lembre-se: o operador `//` faz uma divisão inteira jogando fora o resto, ou seja, aquilo que é menor que o divisor; O operador `%` devolve apenas o resto da divisão inteira jogando fora o resultado, ou seja, tudo que é maior ou igual ao divisor.

Tentei de várias maneiras, mas o resultado continua dando zero. Só tenho essa tentativa anotada porque eu fui fazendo por cima:

```
n = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))

soma = 0

while (n > 0):

    resto = n % 10
    n = (n - resto)/10
    soma = soma + resto


print("A soma dos números é: ", n)
```

Comment: 1- só a barra é divisão de ponto flutuante, você deveria usar dupla barra (divisão inteira); 2- não divisão inteira, não precisa subtrair o resto

Comment: `n = n//10` usando o operador divisão inteira sem tirar o resto

Answer (score 17):

Caso queira explorar soluções alternativas, proponho uma que foge da dica do enunciado.

```
n = input("Digite um número inteiro: ")

print(sum(int(i) for i in n))
```

A função nativa `sum` calcula a soma dos itens de um objeto iterável. Por padrão, a função `input` retorna uma string, que é iterável no Python. Como queremos a soma algébrica dos dígitos, basta converter cada um para o tipo inteiro.

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Gns5/0) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Y933YT).

> **Nota**: Funciona apenas para valores inteiros positivos, visto que tratando o valor como *string*, o sinal de menos é considerado como um caractere.

Answer (score 7):

Para que seu algoritmo funcione, é preciso pegar o ultimo dígito do número, e armazenar este valor em algum lugar, em seguida, remova este número do dígito original, e faça isso enquanto tiver dígitos no número.

```
def somar_digitos(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10 # Soma `s` ao ultimo numeral de `n`
        n //= 10 # Remove o ultimo numero de `n`
    return s
```

O que este algoritmo faz é simples:
1 - Pega o último digito de `n`;
2 - Soma este digito na variável `s`;
3 - Remove o último dígito do número `n`;
4 - Volta ao passo 1;

Comment: Acredito que também não funcione para valores negativos, pois o mesmo seria avaliado como falso na condição do `while`. Alterar para `while n != 0` talvez resolveria o problema.

Answer (score 5):

Minha solução parecida com a sua:

```
x = int(input("Numero: "))

soma = 0

while (x != 0):
    resto = x % 10
    x = (x - resto)//10
    soma = soma + resto
print(soma)
```

Answer (score 4):

Estou atrasado em uns dois anos, mas na minha solução, como o enunciado pedia acerca de números maiores que zero, fiz a implementação de um if casual que dá acesso a todo o while em questão, caso contrário, ele só exibe uma mensagem dizendo que o número é inválido.

```
 numero = int(input('numero: '))
    if numero > 0:
        soma = 0
        while numero != 0:
            resto = numero % 10
            numero = (numero - resto) // 10
            soma = soma + resto
        print(f'soma: {soma}')
    else:
        print('numero invalido...')
```

Answer (score 3):

Apenas para dar mais uma opção, e mencionar um caso que foi apenas citado - mas não resolvido - em outras respostas (quando o número é negativo):

```
# ajuste para o caso de n ser negativo
n = abs(n)

soma = 0
while n > 0:
    n, d = divmod(n, 10)
    soma += d
```

Eu uso `divmod`, que já retorna o resultado da divisão e o resto da mesma em uma tupla - a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) diz que para números inteiros o resultado de `divmod(a, b)` é o mesmo que `(a // b, a % b)`, então é equivalente a fazer estas operações separadamente.

---

Outra opção - meio *over engineered* para este caso - é criar um gerador que retorna os dígitos do número, assim posso usá-lo com [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
def digitos(n):
    n = abs(n)
    while n > 0:
        n, d = divmod(n, 10)
        yield d

n = int(input('Digite um número: '))
soma = sum(digitos(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Também estava com dúvida nesse programa, e baseado no seu consegui fazendo os ajustes abaixo.

```
n = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))

soma = 0

while (n > 0):

    resto = n % 10
    n = n // 10
    soma = soma + resto


print("A soma dos números é: ", soma)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz esse código bem simples. Estou iniciando então acho que pode ajudar as pessoas que também estão com esse problema e estão iniciando em python.
Tranformei partes da string em inteiro.

```
x = input('Digite um número positivo maior que 0\n')
if int(x) > 0:
    i = 0
    s = 0
    while i < len(x):
        s = s + int(x[i])
        i = i + 1
    print(f'A soma dos números é: {s}')
else:
    print('Digite Valores Válidos')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_alg(numero): # Função para somar os algarismos de um número
    a = 0
    for n in range(len(str(numero))):
        n = numero // 10 ** n % 10
        a = a + n
        n = n / 10
    print a
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é utilizar a função [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) do módulo [functools](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html)

```
from functools import reduce

n = input("Digite um número inteiro: ")
print(reduce(lambda *args: sum(args), map(int, n), 0))
```

- `reduce()` aplica uma função de dois argumentos cumulativamente aos itens dum iterável de modo a reduzir o iterável a um único valor.
- `lambda *args: sum(args)` é uma função anônima que retorna a [soma](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sum) de seus argumentos.
- `map(int, n)` aplica a função de conversão para inteiro a cada digito da string.

<sup>Veja o exemplo no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/u6XZHx)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ola, fiz assim:
espero que ajude ;)

```
numero = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))
    
    if numero > 0:
            soma = 0
            while numero != 0:
                resto = numero % 10
                numero = (numero - resto) // 10
                soma = soma + resto
            print(soma)
    else: 
     print(numero)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
n = int (input (“Digite um numero inteiro:”))
soma = 0
      while (n = 0):
               resto =numero % 10
               n = (n - resto) / / 10
              soma = soma + resto
printf (“A soma dos numeros e”, soma“)
else:

printf (“numero valido:”)
else:

print (“numero invalido:”)
```

Comment: Tem certeza que isso é Python? Fora alguns erros de sintaxe, a função `printf` não existe nativamente na linguagem.