# Como somar os valores de um index?

Tags: array, python-3.x, lista, índices

Sou novo em python e preciso fazer um programa que some os dígitos que pertencem à mesma posição de uma lista, por exemplo:

```
Lista = ['22659', '387685', '89546']
```

O resultado da soma de lista[0] seria 24 (2+2+6+5+9), colocando todos as somas numa outra lista ficaria:

```
resultado = ['24', '37', '32']
```

O código que tenho por enquanto apenas separa os dígitos um por um, mas não sei se é a melhor maneira de resolver o problema:

```
for x in lista:
   for k in x:
      print(k)
```

Comment: Que soma seria essa para chegar nesse resultado? Somar cada caractere da string? E qual foi o código que você já fez?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Calcular some de digitos de um numero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194098/5878).

Comment: Sim, seria somar 2+2+6+5+9. O código que eu tenho até agora apenas separa os digitos um por um, mas não tem distinção de quando acaba o lista[0] pra lista [1]

Comment: Se achar que a pergunta que citei não resolve o problema, edite sua pergunta e adicione o seu código. Isso facilitará identificarmos sua dificuldade.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, talvez fique mais fácil de entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples de se fazer é bem semelhante ao que você tem agora:

```
lista = ['22659', '387685', '89546']

resultado = []
for sequencia in lista:
    soma = 0
    for valor in sequencia:
        soma = soma + int(valor)
    resultado.append(soma)

print(resultado)
```

A única coisa é que você precisará ter uma variável de controle `soma`, que será a soma dos dígitos e lembrar de converter sempre o caractere para `int`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/yERDjd).

Avançando um pouco no nível de código, você pode utilizar *list comprehension* como alternativa para calcular a soma dos algarismos:

```
lista = ['22659', '387685', '89546']

resultado = []

for sequencia in lista:
    soma = sum(int(valor) for valor in sequencia)
    resultado.append(soma)

print(resultado)
```

Veja que a linha:

```
soma = sum(int(valor) for valor in sequencia)
```

Substitui por inteiro o segundo `for`. Eles, para fins práticos, são equivalentes.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/AHQPbz).

E se ainda desejar melhorar o código, você pode substituir o `for` que percorre a lista por uma chamada à função `map`, visto que o objetivo do `for` é gerar uma nova lista com base nos valores originais. Semanticamente, você estará fazendo o mapeamento da lista, então pode fazer:

```
lista = ['22659', '387685', '89546']

resultado = map(lambda sequencia: sum(int(valor) for valor in sequencia), lista)

print(list(resultado))
```

Neste caso, o retorno da função `map` será um *generator*, então para exibir todo o resultado é preciso converter para lista com `list`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/HQPUcK).

As três soluções geram os mesmos resultados, mas cada uma possui suas próprias particularidades. Não é esperado que você saiba ou entenda as três logo de início, mas espero que sirva de direção de estudos.

Comment: Isso deu muito certo. Muito obrigado