# Como somar dígitos de um número até "1" dígito?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso somar todos os dígitos de um número até que o resultado desta soma seja um número de apenas "**1**" algarismo, ou seja, enquanto o número de algarismo de um determinado número for maior que **1**, devo somar os seus respectivos algarismos. Desta forma, quando o número de algarismos for igual a **1** a soma deve ser encerrada, exibindo o resultado.

**Exemplo:**

Insere-se o número 155. Soma-se seus dígitos (1 + 5 + 5), obtendo-se o resultado **11**. Como o número **11** é formado por dois algarismos, então, soma-se novamente seus dígitos (1 + 1), obtendo-se o valor **2**. Então, como o valor **2** possui apenas **1** algarismo, a soma será encerrada, exibindo dessa forma o valor **2**.

Cheguei a montar uma linha mas não está funcionando:

```
n1 = int(input("Pessoa 1: digite um numero:"))

soma1 = 0

while((n1//10) != 0):

    while(n1 != 0):

        resto = n1 % 10

        n1 = n1//10

        soma1 = soma1 + resto

    n1 = soma1

print("Sua soma é:", soma1)
```

Comment: Escolha uma das soluções [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194098/112052) e vá repetindo isso até a soma ser menor que 10

Comment: Foi exatamente o que fiz, mas o primeiro while não funciona.

Answer (score 3):

Sobre o algoritmo para somar os dígitos, você pode escolher qualquer um [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194098/112052).

Tendo isso, basta ir calculando a soma, até ela ser menor que 10 (que é quando ela tem somente um dígito). Algo assim:

```
n = int(input("Pessoa 1: digite um numero:"))

# ajuste para o caso do número digitado ser negativo
# também inicializa a soma, para o caso do número já ser inicialmente menor que 10 (pois aí não entra no while)
soma = n = abs(n)

# enquanto o número for maior ou igual a 10 (ou seja, com mais que um dígito), continua
while n >= 10:
    # calcula a soma dos dígitos
    soma = 0
    while n > 0:
        n, d = divmod(n, 10)
        soma += d

    # atualiza o número com o valor da soma
    n = soma

print(f'valor final: {soma}')
```

Ou seja, enquanto o número for maior ou igual a 10 (tem mais que um dígito), eu continuo o *loop*.

Vale notar também que a `soma` tem que ser inicializada com zero **dentro** do *loop*, já que você quer calcular a soma dos dígitos do valor atual do número. Da forma que você fez, a soma é acumulada e o valor dela vai aumentando, e por isso nunca sai do `while`.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é associar **[Expressões de atribuição](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)** juntamente com **[Expressões geradoras](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)**.

Neste caso o código ficaria:

```
x = input("Digite um número: ")

while (s := sum(int(i) for i in x)) > 9:
    x = str(s)
print(f'O resultado é: {s}')
```

Observe que este código captura dígitos no formato de string. Em seguida, a **expressão geradora** se responsabilizará em calcular a soma de todos os dígitos da string convertidos em inteiros. Posteriormente, o bloco **while** verificará se o resultado da **expressão de atribuição** associada à variável **s** é maior que **9**. Caso positivo, o valor de **x** será atualizado como sendo a string de **s** e a expressão geradora será novamente executada, só que desta vez, com o novo valor - que é a string de **s**.

Note que enquanto o valor atribuído à expressão de atribuição for maior que **9**, os cálculos serão refeitos. Caso contrário, o laço de repetição **while** é encerrado e o valor será exibido.

**Testando o código:**

Imagine que ao executar o respectivo código digitássemos o valor:

```
155
```

O código seria executado e nos forneceria como resultado o valor **11**. Pois...

```
1 + 5 + 5 = 11
```

Agora, como **11 é maior que 9**, a expressão geradora será novamente executada, produzindo como resultado o valor **2**. Pois...

```
1 + 1 = 2
```

Uma vez que **2 é menor ou igual a 9**, o laço é encerrado exibindo como resultado o valor **2**.

---

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é aplicar os conceitos da
**[Prova dos nove fora](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prova_dos_noves)**, realizando uma **SUTIL** alteração na resposta final. Alteração esta que consiste em substituir resultado final por **9**, caso o mesmo seja **0**.

**Por que esta alteração?**

A prova dos nove fora nada mais é do que o **resto da divisão inteira de um número "n" por 9**. Desta forma, se um número "n" for um múltiplo de **9**, logo, o resto da divisão será **0**. Só que, pela lógica do seu código, só será permitido respostas entre **1 e 9**. Então, se o resultado da prova dos nove fora for **0** devemos substitui-lo por **9**.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** Se o valor digitado for **None** - vazio - o programa deverá retornar o valor **0**.

Com esta lógica podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return 0 if not n else 9 if (r := n % 9) == 0 else r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = int(input())
    resp = digital_root(number)

    print(resp)
```

Observe que este código captura o valor digitado e verifica se o mesmo é **None**. Caso positivo, retorna **0**. Caso negativo, calcula o resto de sua divisão por **9**. Caso o valor da expressão de atribuição atribuida à variável **r** seja **0** o valor será substituído por **9**. Caso contrário, o valor da variável **r** será exibida.

**NOTA:**

**ESTA QUESTÃO FOI DISPONIBILIZADA PELA PLATAFORMA CODEWARS**, cujo link é: **[Sum of Digits / Digital Root](https://www.codewars.com/kata/541c8630095125aba6000c00/train/python)**

Answer (score -1):

Para resolver esse problema podemos utilizar o seguinte programa

```
def sum (n): # Realiza a soma 
    s = 0
    for i in n: # Percorre toda a string
        s += int(i)
    # Converte cada posição para um tipo inteiro e soma
    return str(s)

n = input()

while True:
    # Se n ainda tiver mais de um dígito ele continuará somando seus algarismos
    if len(n) > 1:
        n = sum(n)
    else:
        break
        
print(n)
```