# Exercício em Python - Somar os algarismos de um número inteiro qualquer

Tags: python, lista

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte exercício:

> Escreva um programa que leia um número inteiro maior do que zero e
> devolva, na tela, a soma de todos os seus algarismos. Por exemplo, ao
> número 251 corresponderá o valor 8(2 + 5 + 1). Se o número lido não
> for maior do que zero, o programa terminará com a mensagem "Número
> inválido".

Minha dúvida é como separar cada algarismo para possibilitar a soma. Minha ideia foi gerar uma [lista](/questions/tagged/lista) a partir da variável [inteira](/questions/tagged/inteira), convertendo-a antes para uma [string](/questions/tagged/string), mas não obtive sucesso. O código que eu implementei seque abaixo:

```
print("Informe um número inteiro maior que zero: ", end="")
num = int(input())

if num <= 0:
    print("\nNúmero inválido!")
else:
    lista = list(num.__str__())
    soma = 0
    for n in lista:
        soma = soma + int(lista[n])
    print(f"\n{soma}")
```

Agradeço qualquer orientação.

Comment: Era só fazer `int(n)` em vez de `int(lista[n])`. No link indicado acima tem outras soluções também, inclusive [uma que trata de números negativos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478821/112052) (que é um caso que a sua não funciona)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.